# How to concatenate a date variable and string variable in unix?

Tags: shell-script

Suppose there are 2 variables as below

$sFileName="test" 
 sSysDate=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

How to concatenate the 2 variables to form 
test_20191030123803

Thanks
Gautam

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways.
`sFileDate="${sFileName}_${sSysDate}"` Note the {}s are optional
`sFileDate="$sFileName_$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S )`
You can even do this in the date command, if you are careful. I have never tried to include a variable in the format. You could do it this way.
`sFileDate=$( date +"test_"+%Y%m%d%H%M%S )`
I do not know if this will work
`sFileDate=$( date "+${sFileName}_%Y%m%d%H%M%S )`

Some of these are OS and shell dependent.
If $( date ) does not work, you may have to enclose your command in back ticks instead: 'date '

Comment: You need curly braces in `${sFileName}_`, to keep it from thinking the "_" is part of the variable name. I'd also recommend not using `${sFileName}` as part of the format string for the `date` command, just in case it contains anything weird that the `date` command would try to parse and act on.